# libzip function to find index of filename doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, zip, archive, unzip, libzip

I started learning libzip today everything is going great, it's just that I can't get the zip_name_locate to work and I can't find any tutorials/examples/documentation that explains it(well the documentation does but I can't get it to work). [Documentation 1](http://linux.die.net/man/3/zip_name_locate), [Documentation 2](http://nih.at/libzip/zip_name_locate.html) ( I can't get any of these to work, the Documentation 2 page also has some enums that apparently haven't been declared in my scope)

So first, my zip archive opens correctly as I can replace and add files to it. I've got terminal output that shows the paths of the indexes (from the zip_get_name function).

Number of files in archive: 3
dummy/
dummy/dummy1/
dummy/dummy1/dummytxt

No matter which one of these I try to find the index of, I always get the index of "dummy/" which is 0, I've also tried with all different enums 
(ZIP_FL_COMPRESSED, ZIP_FL_ENCRYPTED, ZIP_FL_NOCASE, ZIP_FL_NODIR, ZIP_FL_RECOMPRESS, ZIP_FL_UNCHANGED and 0).

(This "dummy/dummy1/" returns 0, which according to zip_get_name is "dummy/")

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I found a "workaround" using the zip_stat structure.

```
struct zip_stat stat;
zip_stat_init(&stat);
zip_stat(zipPointer, "dummy/dummy1/dummytxt", 0, &stat);
std::cout << "name= " <<stat.name << ", index= " << stat.index << std::endl;
```

This would print "name= dummy/dummy1/dummytxt, index= 2". You can also use "zip_stat_index" to build the zip_stat structure by the index instead.
Here you have some documentation for the zip_stat struct and what you can use it for, it seems very useful. [Documentation1](http://nih.at/libzip/zip_stat.html), [Documentation2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/zip_stat), [Documentation3](http://fossies.org/dox/libzip-0.11.2/structzip__stat.html).

Oh and also if you have problems that the debugger says that stat has not been declared in this scope make sure you write it like this: `struct zip_stat stat;`. You've probably missed the struct in front of the declaration.